# Edição de tabelas, campo DateField

Tags: django, python-2.7, formatação

Em um dos insert's da minha aplicação, eu tenho um campo *DateField*, A princípio não há nenhum erro ao salvar as datas no Banco de Dados (**SQLite3**), eu informo uma data no formato `DD/MM/AAAA`, e ela é salva no formato `AAAA/MM/DD` no banco.

Ao editar alguma tabela do banco os campos já vem preenchidos com as informações já salvas com exceção do campo de data, no *Firefox* ele vem preenchido no formato: "11 de Julho de 2014", já no *Chrome* o campo de data não vem preenchido com a data que eu quero editar.

models.py:

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):

    codigo = models.CharField('Codigo', max_length = 10)
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length = 100)
    d_nasc = models.DateField('Data de Nascimento')
    cpf = models.CharField('CPF',max_length = 14)
    telefone = models.CharField('Telefone',max_length = 12)
    endereco = models.CharField('Endereço',max_length = 200)
    email = models.EmailField('E-mail',max_length = 75)
    tipo = models.CharField('Tipo',max_length = 100)

    biblioteca = models.ForeignKey(Biblioteca, blank=True, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome
```

forms.py

```
class FormPessoa (forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Pessoa
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def upPessoa(request, id):

    oPessoa = Pessoa.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormPessoa(request.POST, instance=oPessoa)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('nPesqUsuario'))
    else:
        form = FormPessoa(instance=oPessoa)

    return render(request,'edicao_usuario.html',
                {
                    'form':form,
                    'codigo':id,
                }
            )
```

Como faço para que ao editar as tabelas esse campo de data já venha preenchido com a data salva no Banco no formato `DD/MM/AAAA`?

Não quero ter que salvar todos os campos com o field `CharField`!

O projeto completo esta no [GitHub](https://github.com/Sniickers/Two).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No *Django 1.7* o formato brasileiro é identificado automaticamente, pelo menos é o que está acontecendo comigo. Já no *Django 1.6* eu adicionava no forms.py o formato da data, ex:

```
data_de_nascimento = forms.DateField(
    label=_(u'Data de Nascimento:'), 
    input_formats=["%d/%m/%Y",], 
    widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y')
)
```

No banco o formato salvo será o padrão `Y-m-d`, mas no template/forms o Django vai apresentar o formato que você definir.